# Highstock stock tools toolbar overlaying tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I have a issue with highcharts highstock stock tools toolbar. Its always overlaying the charts tooltip. Changing z-index is not resolving the issues.

Correlating git issues also don't show any solutions

- https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12236
- https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14086

How can I make the tooltip to be the highest layer?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour occurs, because the tooltip use SVG to generate border and background, while stockTools.gui use HTML tags, which overlay the SVG container.

To prevent this behaviour set `tooltip.outside` to `true`.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ks3a2jc6/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.outside